# Progressbar + скачивание файла с url

Tags: python

Как заставить задвигаться progressbar при скачивании файла с url, исходя из размера файла? Перед этим надо узнать его размер. Скачиваю так

```
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen("http://url.ru/file.zip")
a = open("file.zip")
a.write(url)
a.close()
```

Comment: @gcc2me, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Открыв url с помощью urlopen можно прочитать заголовки http, если сервер отдает какой-то файл, то он выставляет заголовок Content-Length. Если url будет вести на страницу, то заголовок выставлен не будет.
Рабочий пример. Для своей программы делайте в соответствии с Вашими нуждами.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import urllib
url=urllib.urlopen('http://localhost/test.zip')
f=open('/var/www/temp.zip', 'w')
totalLength=float(url.headers['content-length'])
dwnLength=0
tmp=url.read(1024)
while(tmp!=''):
    f.write(tmp)
    dwnLength+=len(tmp)
    print str(dwnLength/totalLength*100)+'%'
    tmp=url.read(1024)
f.close()
```

Comment: В данном случае лучше использовать urllib2.urlopen. Потому что urllib сразу открывает ссылку, на что уходит лишнее время. Также, можно получать текущий размер файла через os.path.getsize()

Comment: @mrDoctorWho Вы правы urllib2 лучше.

Comment: Я был неправ: urllib.urlopen не читает файл по ссылке сразу.

Comment: Не суть, все равно лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Быть может, правильнее использовать `urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)`?